# Allow a TFS 210 User to Change Their Password

Tags: passwords

We work with a group of contractors that need access to our TFS 2010 server.  I've got Active Directory running for our office, so every user has an AD account.  Is there a way the TFS users can change their passwords through TFS? I've changed passwords before by having users RDP into computers and changing their account information there, but I'd rather not give the contractors RDP access (they just don't need it).

I tried selecting "user mush change password at next login", but TFS seems not to respond to that.

The only login vehicle the contractors use is TFS.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, TFS doesn't provide a mechanism to change passwords.  Your users will need to use some integration to Active Directory to change their password.  It needn't necessarily be through an RDP session, as long as they can hit Active Directory's LDAP server, you should be able to allow this.

IIS ships with a tool called **[IISADMPWD](http://www.misreply.org/2009/the-awesomeness-of-iisadmpwd/)** that lets users change their password over the web.

In addition, you can build your own tool to change the password, like other people have done in [PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/17/how-to-change-a-user-s-active-directory-password-with-powershell.aspx) or [perl](http://www.evanhoffman.com/evan/2010/01/13/victory-change-active-directory-password-via-ldap-through-browser/).  In addition, there appear to be various commercial tools to enable this.